# How to parse HTML element?

Tags: string, scala

I have long string with Currency that look like the following :

```
...<option value="USD">USD - United States Dollar</option>    <option value="JPY">JPY - Japanese Yen</option>...
```

What is the fastest way in order to extract 2 values:

```
USD
USD - United States Dollar
```

Comment: I don't know what the "fastest" way is, but [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org).

Comment: You mean how do you extract `X` and `Y` from the string `<option value=X>Y</option>`?

Comment: @Assaf Yes, this is what i want to do

Comment: Can we have the whole String? The substring you gave suggests it actually has XML format, in which case you can load it as XML with `scala.xml.XML.loadString(yourStringHere)` and then extract elements, as shown in [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-extract-data-from-xml-nodes-in-scala) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really just getting certain substrings out of a string then I'd go with a regex here.

Use a capturing group (make sure it's not greedy) to get the parts of the string that interest you (in this case the `value` property and the tag content).

```
val str =
  """<option value="USD">USD - United States Dollar</option><option value="JPY">JPY - Japanese Yen</option>"""
val pattern = """<option value="(.+?)">(.+?)</option>""".r

pattern.findAllMatchIn(str).foreach(x => println(x.group(1) + " " + x.group(2)))
/* output:
 * USD USD - United States Dollar
 * JPY JPY - Japanese Yen
 */
```

Comment: Maybe you can directly use: `pattern.findAllMatchIn(str).foreach(x => println(x.group(1) + " " + x.group(2)))`

Comment: Correct sir, consider me chastised.

Comment: Using regex to parse html is [generally not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2292812)

Comment: OK, that was extremely... poetic. I agree with that 100% though, so OP, if the string is inside an greater HTML, you should not, repeat should not use this solution. If however it's just a string then go ahead.